# Get MIME Type with Tika with part of a file

Tags: apache-tika

Is it possible with [Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) to get the MIME Type or other meta data without loading the whole file?

I could code a script to get the first 1MB. I am thinking of doing this to take off some of the load on [Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) and my server.

Comment: What kind of file would this be for? Many file types Tika can detect with just a few KB of data, but others (eg container formats) need the whole file to work out what they contain and hence the exact type

Comment: ok I did not know that. It would be documents, videos, and images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For container-based formats, Apache Tika needs the whole file to be sure of the type. Container formats include pretty much everything based on a zip file (Word `.docx`, OpenDocumentFormat `.odf`, iWorks etc), anything based on the OLE2 format (Excel `.xls`, Hangul, MSI etc), and pretty much all multimedia formats. You can often take a good guess based on the filename and the container type, but to be sure you need to process the whole file to identify the contents and hence the file type

For everything else, if Tika can detect the file type, then only the first few tens of KBs are needed, often even only the first few hundred bytes. (Depends on the format in question - different ones have their predictable signatures in different places)

If you don't need Tika's very best detection guess, but can make do with a slightly lower certainty (especially on container-based formats), then simply just give Tika the start of the file. Or tell Tika to only use the mime magic detector without any of the container-specific detectors.